# select all post_meta starting with "temp_size" based on post ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

in my worpdress database I have rows where post_id is the page's id and meta keys are temp_size45, temp_size99,....

I would like to show all those values from those meta keys that start with "temp_size"

So then it would look like this

temp_size45 value
temp_size99 value
...
....
so it would be something like this SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = all that start with temp_size

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM   wp_postmeta 
WHERE  post_id = <some post id> AND meta_key LIKE 'temp_size%'
```